# Does the order in which the dplyr functions,used in pipeline matters?

Tags: r, dplyr

I noticed that the order in which the dplyr functions when used in pipeline impacts the result. for example:

```
iris %>%   
  group_by(Species) %>%   
     mutate(Sum = sum(Sepal.Length))
```

produces different results than this:

```
iris %>% 
  mutate(Sum = sum(Sepal.Length)) %>%
     group_by(Species)
```

Can anyone explain the reason for this, and if there are any specific order in which they have to be defined, please mention the same.
Thank you

FYI: iris is an inbuilt dataset in R,use data(iris) to load it. I was trying to add a new column, sum of sepal lengths for each species.

Comment: I’m puzzled: **of course** the order matters. dplyr is no different in this regard from any other code (in a sequentially executed programming language). What makes you think the order wouldn’t matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the order matters.

The pipe is equivalent to:

`iris<-group_by(iris, Species)
 iris<-mutate(iris, Sum = sum(Sepal.Length))`

If you change the order, you change the result. If you group by species first, you'll have the result of the sum by species (I guess that's what you want).
However if you group by species after the sum, this sum will correspond to summing the Sepal length for all species.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the order matters because each part of the pipe is evaluated on its own, starting from the first through to the last pipe-part and the result of the previous pipe (or original dataset) is piped forward to the next following pipe-part. That means, if you use `group_by` *after* the `mutate` as in your example, the `mutate` will be done without grouping.

One side effect is that you can create complex and long pipes where you control the order of operations (by positioning them at the right part of the pipe) and you don't need to start a new pipe after an operation is finished.